# Как открыть и прочитать srcds.exe с помощью python?

Tags: python, io, ос, subprocess

Я полный новичок в python, хочу написать программу, которая будет открывать srcds.exe (Сервер Source) и читать ее, выводя все в консоль, пробовал и os и subprocess, ничего не помогает

```
import os
import codecs
import subprocess
 
srcds = subprocess.Popen("D:\SteamCMD\steamapps\common\EqRp\srcds.bat", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = False)

#subprocess.run("srcds.bat -console")
#with subprocess.Popen("srcds.bat") as f:


print (str(srcds))
```

Comment: Для путей с таким слешем используйте raw-строки, т.к. перед кавычкой добавьте `r` это поможет уберечься от странных багов. Добавил пример в своем ответе

Comment: Можно работать и с батником, но лучше обычно вызывать сам исполняемый файл с параметрами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю что выводит `srcds.bat`, но покажу 2 способа получения данных.

Для теста завожу батник `1.bat`, который запускает питон, в котором выводятся значения от 0 до 4 раз в 1 секунду:

```
@echo off
echo arg1=%1
python -c "import time;[(print(i), time.sleep(1)) for i in range(5)]"
```

##### Способ 1: считываем из `stdout` при работе программы:

```
import subprocess

srcds = subprocess.Popen(r"1.bat -console", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, universal_newlines=True)
for line in srcds.stdout:
    line = line.rstrip()
    print(line)
```

##### Способ 2: дожидаемся окончания программы и считываем результат:

```
import subprocess

srcds = subprocess.Popen(r"1.bat -console", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, universal_newlines=True)
srcds.wait()
out, err = srcds.communicate()
print(out)
```

##### Результат:

```
arg1=-console
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Srcds.exe (В коде srcds.bat, потому что пробовал все, что придет в голову) открывает собственный интерфейс, который не может прочитать питон, обычно его открывают через батник с методом -console, не подскажите как этод метод передать в питон? Также при открытии выдает OSErrod: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32, у самого стоит 64x виндовс.

Comment: @Tyash, да так и передавайте: пробел и аргументы. Обновил ответ с примером

Comment: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

Comment: Я разобрался. Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Если несложно, можете подсказать: можно ли писать в этот exe файл какие-нибудь команды с помощью питона?

Comment: @Tyash, пожалуйста :) отметьте и примите мой ответ :)

Comment: @Tyash, например, через `communicate` можно писать команды используя параметр `input`, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8e24ad5775dac74207d2e2758bdd08fdc8f0aa82/subprocess_example/run_and_input_text__num_sum/main.py#L12. Не забудьте указать в `Popen` параметр `stdin=PIPE`. Думаю, что и по аналогии с `srcds.stdout` можно в `stdin` писать, но, думаю, вариант с `communicate` удобнее

Comment: Надеюсь это будет последним моим вопросом к Вам. После запуска и некоторого времени ожидания вылезает это: CTextConsoleWin32::GetLine: !GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents

Comment: Как я понял, stdin посылает слишком много обращений в консоль, что вызывает исключение. Можно ли как-нибудь единоразово послать обращение в консоль?

Comment: @Tyash, какая-то ошибка ПО стима, гугл выдал подобные ошибки и темы, например: https://steamcommunity.com/app/4000/discussions/5/1642043267233474988/?l=german

Comment: я убрал в popen stdin и все снова в порядке, можно ли использовать communicate без stdin?

Comment: @Tyash, неа, без stdin не получится из кода послать данные в communicate